# PHP foreach loop through multidimensional array echo output group by one key->value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a mutidimensional array:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [place_id] => 2225
            [place_name] => NEW YORK
            [alarm] => PING
            [name_connection] => New-York-01
            [name_connection_id] => 11175
            [status] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [place_id] => 2225
            [place_name] => NEW YORK
            [alarm] => PING
            [name_connection] => New-York-03
            [name_connection_id] => 4324
            [status] => 1

        )   
    [2] => Array
        (
            [place_id] => 1345
            [place_name] => DALLAS
            [alarm] => PING
            [name_connection] => Dallas-03
            [name_connection_id] => 6666
            [status] => 1

        )       

)
```

If i use foreach i get the output, but i would like to get the output grouped by the first key-Value or second (place_id or place_name) if they are the same. So basicly i woudl like to get the output like this:

**NEW YORK**
New-York-01 | 11175 | 1
New-York-03 | 4324  | 1
**DALLAS**
Dallas-03 | 6666 | 1

If i use standard foreach:

```
 foreach($place as $rowplace){

            $place_name3 = $rowplace['place_name'];
            $name_connection3 = $rowplace['name_connection'] ;

            echo' 
            <font color="green"> <b>'.$place_name3 .'</b><br> 
'.$name_connection3.'</font> <br>'; 
            }
```

I gout output like this:

**NEW YORK**
New-York-01 | 11175 | 1
**NEW YORK**
New-York-03 | 4324  | 1
**DALLAS**
Dallas-03 | 6666 | 1

So NEW YORK (place_name) is duplicated. How can i merge or group by results based on that key-value?

Thanks, Misko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic solution is tracking a `place_name` and see if it has changed:

```
// variable to track previous place name
$prev_place_name = '';

foreach($place as $rowplace){
    $place_name3 = $rowplace['place_name'];

    // current place name differs from previous:
    if ($place_name3 != $prev_place_name) {
        echo '<font color="green"> <b>'.$place_name3 .'</b></font>';
        $prev_place_name = $place_name3;
    }

    $name_connection3 = $rowplace['name_connection'] ;
    echo '<br>'.$name_connection3; 
}
```

Comment: Future readers, if your subarrays are not ordered by `place_name`, call `usort()` to prepare the array before looping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new var with old place name, check if it == place_name from your array, if it doesn't echo place name, if it does echo connection only

Edit: This also means you will have to put it in order of place name, eg New York, New York, Dallas and not New York, Dallas, New York. But since your array is already set up that way you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution using additional array of grouped "places"(by `place_name` key):

```
$places = [
    [
        'place_id' =>  2225,
        'place_name' =>  'NEW YORK',
         'alarm' =>  'PING',
         'name_connection' =>  'New-York-01',
         'name_connection_id' =>  11175,
         'status' =>  1,
    ],
    [
        'place_id' =>  2225,
        'place_name' =>  'NEW YORK',
        'alarm' =>  'PING',
        'name_connection' =>  'New-York-03',
        'name_connection_id' =>  4324,
        'status' =>  1,
    ],
    [
        'place_id' =>  1345,
        'place_name' =>  'DALLAS',
        'alarm' =>  'PING',
        'name_connection' =>  'Dallas-03',
        'name_connection_id' =>  6666,
        'status' =>  1,
    ]
];

$grouped = [];
foreach ($places as $place) {
    // constructing the row with columns
    $line = implode("|", [$place['name_connection'], $place['name_connection_id'], $place['status']]);
    if (isset($grouped[$place['place_name']])) {
        $grouped[$place['place_name']] .= "</br>". $line;
    } else {
        $grouped[$place['place_name']] = $line;
    }
}

// outputting `places` data in tabular form
foreach ($grouped as $k => $columns) {
    echo '<font color="green"> <b>'. $k .'</b></br>'
            . $columns .'</font> </br>';
}
```

The output(of course, in browser you'll see bolded/colored text):

```
 NEW YORK
New-York-01|11175|1
New-York-03|4324|1 
 DALLAS
Dallas-03|6666|1
```